# Unable to authenticate Woo commerce API

Tags: php, curl, woocommerce

I have used this code so far:-

```
 <?php
        $url    = "http://localhost/wordpress/wc-api/v3/orders?oauth_consumer_key='cs_ffd1bf17f1d66526ebd12e5ad9cf24c986a93dc5'&oauth_timestamp=".time();
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $arrResult = json_decode($result, true);


        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($arrResult);
```

But I'm getting an error

> {"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"oauth_signature parameter is missing"}]}

And I have no clue about **oauth_signature**.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to generate signature using your oauth customer key, detailed steps can be found here:

http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-http